# php mysql : storing only 1 data at time period

Tags: php, mysql

I'm wondering if anyone can suggest a good way to store one data ina a period of time in a mysql database?

Note that I'm referring to a PERIOD of time, not just a datetime. Like.. an hour. Or a day and a half. Or two weeks. Or a year.

Specifically I want to store only one data of time periods every two hours if i had a period of time, at 8am-10pm, 10am-12pm, 12pm-14pm,

Can I do that in php or mysql?

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question so it is clearer as to what you want to do, include some code and what you have already tried.

Comment: here is the situation.. i have to push data to mysql, every 2 hours, e.g at 8 am, 10am, 12am.. during this time periode, only 1 data will acceptable.. if i have done push 1 data at 8am, the system will reject until next periode, at 10am.. the goal is between 8am-10pm, only 1 data saved in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Check this one:

Add new column in a type of `timestamp` to the table of your database.

Use your PHP skills with this tip:

```
$sql = "SELECT $timestamp FROM $table ORDER BY $timestamp DESC LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($conection, "$sql");

if (/*the hour now*/ != /*the hour on $result*/) {
    // allow to store data
} else {
    // don't allow to store data
}
```

Just do the rest, I didn't even review well if there's a mistakes on the code above. Just use your programming skills..

*"However, anyone can improved this answer by revising."*